# Why did God create seasons?

Tags: natural-phenomenon

The Midrash Kohelet say on the verse: "see the work of G-d.." (Ecc. 7:13) -  "when the Holy One, Blessed be He, created Adam, He took him and led him to pass before all the trees of the Garden of Eden and said to him: 'see how beautiful and excellent are my works. All that I have created, I have created for your sake..."

Based on that, what do our sources (talmud, midrash, etc) say about the benefits to humans for the seasons of the year?

Comment: Is a vital use for seasons less meaningful if not mentioned in Jewish sources?

Answer (score 2):

Rav Hirsch goes into detail on this subject in Noach 8:22. He says that the eternal spring that prevailed before the flood led to the slackness and degeneration that wound up causing the flood. This also included the extremely long lives that were common then.

Rav Hirsch states that the constant changes will help man to be able to learn to rely on Hashem and not fall prey to the errors that led to the punishment of the flood. This will also place a limit on the evil that can occur when bad men take power. The changes in the seasons also require that Man work constantly and attempt to make things better.

> Even the mightiest tyrant cannot wield the sceptre much more than seventy years
>
> With the birth of every child an angel enters the world. But as long
>   as the bad ones reached their seven to eight hundred years, a better
>   youth did not get a chance.

An analogy is given to the effect that King Menashe had upon Yehudah by ruling 52 years.

Rav Hirsch also explains that this allowed the development of nations and cultures because of the difficulties of travel and communication. Whil this had to be implemented by the dispersion of Babel, Rav Hirsch points out that it was the natural result of the changes that were part of humanity.